# Why is the derivative of $3^x$ equal to $3^x \cdot \ln 3$

Tags: analysis, derivatives, logarithms, natural-numbers

Our teacher tells us to convert it this way $ 3^x = e^{\ln 3^x}= e^{x\cdot\ln 3}$ and then use the rule $e^u\cdot u'$ but I can't understand where $\ln$ comes from and how $\ln 3^x$ = $x\cdot \ln 3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because by the definition of $\ln$ we have $\ln3^x=x\ln3$ and from here: $$\left(3^x\right)'=\left(e^{x\ln3}\right)'=e^{x\ln3}\cdot\ln3=3^x\ln3.$$
Actually,  $\log_ab$ it's a number $c$ such that $a^c=b$. (Here, $a>0$, $b>0$ and $a\neq1$)

Id est, $a^{\log_ab}=b$.

For $a=e$ we obtain: $e^{\ln{b}}=b$ and $$3^x=\left(e^{\ln3}\right)^x=e^{x\ln3}.$$

Comment: But why do we have to convert it to a natural number and why is there an ln in the exponent? Thats what I dont understand. Sorry if this is a stupid question

Comment: @ythhtrg it's the definition of $\ln$. $\log_ab$ it's a number $c$ such that $a^c=b$. Id est, $a^{\log_ab}=b$. For $a=e$ we obtain: $e^{\ln{b}}=b$ and $3^x=\left(e^{\ln3}\right)^x=e^{x\ln3}.$

Answer (score 0):

And are you familiar with this basic property of logarithms?
$$\log_{b}{x^y}=y\log_{b}{x}$$
You can bring the power out front.

How about this fact?

$$
a=e^{\ln{a}}, a >0
$$

Do you know what the derivative of an exponential function is?

$$
(a^x)'=a^x\ln{a}
$$

This can be proven a number of ways. You can go back to the definition of the limit and prove it that way or you can use logarithmic differentiation:

$$
y=a^x\\
\ln{y}=\ln{a^x}\\
\ln{y}=x\ln{a}\\
(\ln{y})'=(x\ln{a})'\\
\frac{1}{y}y'=\ln{a}\\
y'=y\ln{a}\\
y'=a^x\ln{a}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Any term $x$ can be expressed as power of $e$:

$$x=e^{\ln x}$$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).